# How can I add the Fourier coefficients to a Fourier-series plot?

Tags: plotting, fourier-analysis

I have the given function:

```
points = {{395.4416644777464`, 
    207.63931734339303`}, {391.15890276860114`, 
    240.47382378017346`}, {382.59337935031067`, 
    219.06001523444706`}, {378.3106176411653`, 
    209.0669045797748`}, {369.74509422287485`, 
    177.65998537937617`}, {361.1795708045843`, 
    250.4669344348457`}, {355.46922185905726`, 
    204.78414287062958`}, {346.9036984407667`, 
    236.19106207102823`}, {341.19334949523966`, 
    184.79792156128497`}, {332.6278260769492`, 
    220.48760247082885`}, {326.9174771314222`, 
    214.77725352530183`}, {322.6347154222768`, 
    260.4600450895181`}, {316.9243664767498`, 
    219.06001523444706`}, {314.06919200398636`, 
    241.90141101655524`}, {304.076081349314`, 
    119.12890868772422`}, {295.5105579310235`, 
    327.5566451994606`}, {278.3795110944425`, 
    156.24617683364988`}, {269.8139876761519`, 
    251.8945216712275`}, {264.1036387306249`, 
    196.218619452339`}, {258.39328978509786`, 
    286.1566153443896`}, {249.8277663668073`, 
    233.33588759826466`}, {241.26224294851679`, 
    173.37722367023093`}, {231.26913229384448`, 
    184.79792156128497`}, {224.13119611193568`, 
    286.1566153443896`}, {215.56567269364515`, 
    160.52893854279512`}, {199.86221309344583`, 
    303.28766218097076`}, {184.1587534932465`, 
    72.01852988712619`}, {172.73805560219247`, 
    587.3775222209401`}, {162.74494494752017`, 
    83.43922777818022`}, {149.89665982008435`, 
    260.4600450895181`}, {145.61389811093912`, 
    254.74969614399106`}, {138.47596192903032`, 
    317.56353454478824`}, {131.33802574712158`, 
    183.37033432490318`}, {124.20008956521278`, 
    193.36344497957543`}, {119.91732785606749`, 
    160.52893854279512`}, {112.77939167415872`, 
    214.77725352530183`}, {108.49662996501345`, 
    199.07379392510256`}, {105.64145549224995`, 
    250.4669344348457`}, {101.35869378310466`, 
    324.70147072669704`}, {98.50351931034115`, 
    224.77036417997408`}, {91.36558312843238`, 
    220.48760247082885`}, {81.37247247376007`, 
    96.28751290561604`}, {75.66212352823305`, 
    200.50138116148423`}, {72.80694905546954`, 
    351.82562821795045`}, {54.24831498250671`, 
    154.8185895972681`}, {41.4000298550709`, 
    240.47382378017346`}, {35.68968090954388`, 
    236.19106207102823`}, {32.83450643678037`, 
    280.4462663988626`}, {12.848285127435787`, 
    131.97719381515992`}, {7.1379361819087705`, 227.62553865273765`}};

points2 = {#[[1]], #[[2]] - 72.01852988712619`} & /@ points;


Clear[t];
f[t_] = Piecewise[
   Partition[Sort[points2], 2, 
     1] /. {{a_?NumericQ, b_}, {c_, d_}} :> {b, a <= t < c}];

f1[t_] = f[(172.73805560219247` (t + Pi)/Pi)];
```

which for I generated the Fourier series:

```
FD[t_] = FourierSeries[f1[t], t, 20]
```

Then I'd like to plot the real parts of every Fouriercoefficients on the plot, from 1-20:

```
Re[FourierCoefficient[f1[t], t, 1]]
Re[FourierCoefficient[f1[t], t, 2]]
Re[FourierCoefficient[f1[t], t, 3]]
...

Re[FourierCoefficient[f1[t], t, 20]]
```

However, there are many points, and it is difficult to "harvest" them into a set that can be directly plotted with the Fourier series plot:

```
Four = Plot[{FD[t]}, {t, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

by

```
Show[Four, Epilog -> {PointSize -> Large, Point[{{0, 2}}]}]
```

Are there better ways?

Thanks

attached the image of the real parts of the fourier coefficients on the x axis of a fourier transform of a piecewise function (other than the functtion in this post)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You may extract the real part of the coefficients from FD[t]:

```
res = (FD[t] /. Plus -> List) /. x_ Exp[__] -> Re[x]
```

To plot this you use ListPlot (note the point at index 1 belongs to the DC coefficient, index 2 to the lowest frequency ...):

```
ListPlot[res]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Daniel, but I couldn't get the plot of the coefficients to coincide with the Fourier plot. In fact they are completely unrelated.

Comment: Look at the Fourier Series and check if it is in agreement with the plot.

Comment: That is what I did. They have nothing in common.

Comment: THis are the first few terms of the Fourier Series: `139.85 + (15.8404 + 4.76022 I) E^(-I t) + (15.8404 - 4.76022 I) E^(
  I t) + (4.64917 - 3.3024 I) E^(-2 I t)` Note the plot does not show the DC component because it is too large. Therefore the real terms are: 15.8, 15.8, 4.64, .. and that is what the plot shows.

Comment: It i weird, because I was just given a proof that says that the real of the Fourier coefficients are always points that can be found on the Fourier series  AND the Fourier transform.

Comment: The real parts of the coefficients of the Fourier series are numbers and the Fourier transform is a function????

Comment: The fourier transform is an L1 function. The real parts are to be found on the x coordinate of either the Fourier transform and the fourier series

Comment: Daniel, I attach an image in OP

Comment: HAve you checked that the abscissa of the Fourier transform and the coefficients have the same scale? In "res" the first element belongs to the zero frequency. The second to the positive lowest frequency. The third to the negative lowest frequency. The fourth to twice the positive lowest frequency ...

Comment: Hi Daniel,  do you get a similar plot as I posted in the OP? I give the lemma of relevance: Lemma:
The real part of the Fourier coefficients of some real function $f(t)$ are found directly on the plot of the Fourier series $f(t)$. \\

Comment: The FourierTransform takes data into account from -Infinity to Infinity. The FourierSeries takes data from -P to Pi. You can change frequencies in the range -Pi..Pi by changing the original function above Pi. This does not change the FourierSeries but the FourierTransfrom!

Comment: Yes, while the coefficients remain part of both the plot of the Transform and the Series. But how can I show that in the given plot? It does not coincide.

Comment: This can not be true as stated, there must be something more.

Comment: Daniel, I can mail you the attachment. If you send me a mail at vangsnes.fiolin@gmail.com